# Cron job: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, cron, mediatemple

On a Mediatemple gridserver, I'm trying to run this by a cron set in the control panel:

```
usr/bin/python /home/xxxxx/html/sitemap_gen.py --config=/home/xxxxx/html/config.xml
```

But I get the error "python: can't open file '/home/95809/html/sitemap_gen.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory." But the files are there. MT requires the paths, and there is no difference in the error without the paths.

I can run it manually from ssh:

```
python sitemap_gen.py --config=config.xml
```

and have chmoded the script for execution.

Is there a different way to run this script that will work?

MT doesn't have direct examples of python scripts run by cron, and doesn't offer support.

Is there a way to wrap the script in another script - like a bash script - to get away from having to include the paths or invoke python, which I think might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things i would suggest:

1. Try to run the command manually on the command line if you have access
2. Verify that your user has execute permissions on the file `/home/xxxxx/html/sitemap_gen.py`

EDIT: 
oh duh ... try using the full path to python so if the python executable is in `/usr/bin` it would be : `/usr/bin/python /home/xxx/html/sitemap_gen.py <blah blah blah>`

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that I tried both already. Is there a way to wrap the script in another script - like a bash script - to get away from having to include the paths, which I think might be the problem? Does that make any sense?

Comment: Good point, and when I knew what to look for, MT does say that the path to python is usr/bin/python. But still the same error. Tried moving everything to root but then the sitemap_gen.py can't find the sitemap.xml.gz file, even when I put the full path in the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy script  (Just print somethign ) and run it via crond. Maybe crond doesn't have the necessary permissions to even read the file.

Propably your user have permissions so can execute it, but crond doesn't